# Page reloading after calling jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a div which I am checking for a condition at `$(document).ready(function ())`, then deciding whether to show it or not.

There is a button inside the div which fades out the entire div. The problem is after calling the `fadeout()` function, the `$(document).ready(function ())` gets called again(i.e. the page gets reloaded) and it again satisfies the condition to show the div.

I want to prevent the page from reloading after the `fadeout()` function gets called.

HTML

```
<div class="success"><%: ViewData["successResult"] %>
<br /><br />
<span id="closenotification" class="buttons" onclick="fadeoutbox()"><a href="" ><img src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Images/door_out.png") %>" alt="" />Close</a></span>
</div>
```

javascript

```
function fadeoutbox() {
    $(".success").fadeOut(5000, function () {
        /*$(".success").css("display", "none");
     $("#closenotification").css("display", "none");*/
    });

}

$(function () {
    var successres = '<%= ViewData["successResult"] %>';
    //alert(successres != null);
    if (successres != "") {
        var leftpos = screen.width / 2 - 350;
        var toppos = screen.height / 2 - 125;
        $(".success").css("left", leftpos);
        $(".success").css("top", toppos);
        $(".success").css("display", "block");
        $("#closenotification").css("display", "block");
    }

    if ($(".failure").html() != "") {
        var leftpos = screen.width / 2 - 350;
        var toppos = screen.height / 2 - 125;
        $(".failure").css("left", leftpos);
        $(".failure").css("top", toppos);
        $(".failure").css("display", "block");


    }
});
```

Comment: i think you mean its reloading if you click the link... make this:
<a href="javascript:return false;">some link firing but not reloading pages</a>

Comment: mark also an answer as confirmed and try out yourself also preventDefault() ... theres a difference but both working like you want

Answer (score 1):

You've wrapped the image in a `a` tag. You'll need to use [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to prevent the page from reloading on the click event of the `a` tag. or remove the `a` tag altogether.

Comment: No I can't remove a tag, because I had some css tied to it. ggzone's solution worked

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the `onclick` event into the link element (nested into the `span`) and change your function like so

```
function fadeoutbox(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(".success").fadeOut(5000, function () {
       ...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `onclick="fadeoutbox()"` part and add this handler:

```
$('#closenotification').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fadeoutbox();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

$(function () {

```
var successres = '<%= ViewData["successResult"] %>';
//alert(successres != null);
if (successres != "") {
    var leftpos = screen.width / 2 - 350;
    var toppos = screen.height / 2 - 125;
    $(".success").css("left", leftpos);
    $(".success").css("top", toppos);
    $(".success").css("display", "block");
    $("#closenotification").css("display", "block");

    return;
}

if ($(".failure").html() != "") {
    var leftpos = screen.width / 2 - 350;
    var toppos = screen.height / 2 - 125;
    $(".failure").css("left", leftpos);
    $(".failure").css("top", toppos);
    $(".failure").css("display", "block");

    return;
}
```

});

Comment: add a return statement before the end of both if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

you can do one of these :

1. Put `#` for href
2. return false at the end of the `fadeoutbox`
3. use `e.preventDefault()` like other guys said

Comment: also `e.preventDefault()` is something like `return false`